# Copy constructor called multiple times for custom map values

Tags: c++11, stl, containers, associative-array, copy-constructor

I've just started using maps in C++, I implemented this piece of code where I've used custom datatype for map values. But I haven't understood the copy constructor part. It's being called multiple times only when I use

```
person.insert(make_pair(55,Person("Bob",23)));
person.insert(make_pair(35,Person("Bill",25)));
```

Can someone kindly explain me the working of the copy constructor in this code ??

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>

using namespace std;

class Person{
    private:
        string name;
        int age;
    
    public:
        Person(const Person &other){
            cout<<"Copy Constructor Running !!"<<endl;
            name=other.name;
            age=other.age;
        }
        Person():name(""),age(0){
            
            
        }
        Person(string name,int age):name(name), age(age){
            
           
        }
        void print(){
            cout<<name<<" : "<<age<<endl;
        }
};

int main(){

    map<int,Person> person;
    person[50]=Person("Mike",19);
    person[20]=Person("Julia",20);
    person[30]=Person("Raj",29);
    person[10]=Person("Kendra",20);
    person[70]=Person("Rahul",18);

    person.insert(make_pair(55,Person("Bob",23)));
    person.insert(make_pair(35,Person("Bill",25)));


    
    for(auto it=person.begin();it!=person.end();it++){
    cout<<it->first<<" : ";
    it->second.print();
    }
    
   
   

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Copy Constructor Running !!
Copy Constructor Running !!
Copy Constructor Running !!
Copy Constructor Running !!
10 : Kendra : 20
20 : Julia : 20
30 : Raj : 29
35 : Bill : 25
50 : Mike : 19
55 : Bob : 23
70 : Rahul : 18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Person("Bob",23)` constructs a temporary `Person` instance; let's call it `P`. Then `make_pair(55, P)` constructs a temporary `pair`, copying `P` into its member `pair.second`. Finally, `map::insert` copies elements of that pair into its own data structures.

`person[50]=Person("Mike",19)` doesn't use a copy constructor, but rather a copy assignment operator (which you haven't instrumented and so don't see being called).

If you want to reduce or avoid copies:

```
person.emplace(55, Person("Bob",23));
```

will execute copy constructor once;

```
person.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
               std::forward_as_tuple(55),
               std::forward_as_tuple("Bob", 23));
```

won't call copy constructor at all, but use provided arguments to construct `Person` object directly in the map's internal storage.